# How to add values to column using loop Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I would like to know how I can change the values of a column dynamically as I grab the information from a web scrape.

Currently, I have something like this:

`number     name
12          NA
13          NA
14          NA
15          NA`

and I would like to receive something like this:

`number     name
12          Mike
13          Bob
14          Bobby
15          Mark`

I have tried using this:

`for number in phone_book:
    name = get_name()
    phonebook['names'][number] = name`

and

`phonebook.loc[phonebook.index[number], 'name'] = name`

but it just sets the name of the last number for all:

`number     name
12          Mark
13          Mark
14          Mark
15          Mark`

How could I get it to add each name to its respective number?

Thanks

Comment: `phonebook.loc[phonebook.number == number, 'names'] = name`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you so much, that works! Can you explain why I need the `phonebook.number == number`?

Comment: `phonebook.number == number` looks through the `'number'` columns in your `phonebook` and mark the correct ones. `.loc` gives you access to the corresponding rows/columns.

Answer (score 2):

From your web scrape you could build a dict that looks like this:

```
name = {12: 'Mike', 13: 'Bob', 14: 'Bobby', 15: 'Mark'}
```

Then you can map to your existing frame:

```
df['name']=df['number'].map(name)
df = df.set_index('number')
print(df) 
         
number   name    
12       Mike
13        Bob
14      Bobby
15       Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several way to do it, first like @Quang Hoang comment :

```py
phonebook.loc[phonebook.number == number, 'names'] = name
```

You can also do like this :

```py
for number in phone_book:
    name = get_name()
    phonebook[phonebook["number"] == number] = name
```

or like this :

```py
names = []
for number in phone_book:
    names.append(get_name())
phonebook["name"] = names
```

Note that the prefered method is the first one.